# Problem with running jupyter notebook from docker image

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I have installed the following docker image with the jupyter notebook installed - https://hub.docker.com/layers/tensorflow/tensorflow/2.0.4-gpu-jupyter/images/sha256-926eb2502748f0a45607fb35b99a9a19bf20962f1051e7e0a5965b1c83f2d62a?context=explore.

And when running it with the following command:

`docker run -it --gpus all -p 8888:8888 -u $(id -u):$(id -g) tensorflow/tensorflow:2.0.4-gpu-jupyter`

I cannot open the appearing localhost links (Server not found):

```
http://9f44be49ff10:8888/?token=06bc87bf64e14eb3fc57d3044439ad325ee0f9cc91fd5805
```

And this links works:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=06bc87bf64e14eb3fc57d3044439ad325ee0f9cc91fd5805
```

But sends me to the tensorflow tutorials, which is not the desired behavior, and I would like to see the content of the directory from which I am running it.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution was rather simple. I needed simply to be more attentive, when reading the `Tensorflow` dockerhub.

In order to work in a specific directory, one needed to specify with the flag `-v` as prescribed here https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow:

`docker run -it --rm -v $(realpath ~/notebooks):/tf/notebooks -p 8888:8888 tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-jupyter`

Where `~/notebooks` is a path to the directory you are intending to work in.